Is there a way to set the Remaining Cost of a pjResourceTypeCost Resource Assignment?
I'd like to be able to set the remaining cost of a Cost (pjResourceTypeCost) type resource assignment, but the RemainingCost property of the assignment is read-only, so something like this doesn't work:
assignmentObj.RemainingCost = 5000
When working with a Material (pjResourceTypeMaterial) type resource assignment, you can use the RemainingWork property to set the remaining cost value, but this doesn't work on a Cost type resource assignment.
Is there a way to set the remaining cost value on a cost type resource assignment without using it's TimeScaledValues?
One other note, I've also tried setting the Cost property to a number and then setting ActualCost to another number, thinking the delta between these will set the remaining cost. The only problem with this is that if the parent task of the Assignment is in progress, it messes up the Actual Duration of the task.

Kenny, Probably not what you want but you can set remaining cost for a Cost type resource via foreground processing (i.e. select the assignment row and set the Remaining Cost field value). Sometimes you just gotta punt.

@john-project indeed that is not what I want, but if it's the only option then unfortunately it is what it is.

Kenny, I have run into a few instances wherein the only option to get what I need is to revert to foreground processing (active view selection). I don't like it either, but if it gets me there. . . .
